# Unable to start Deno Vue Vite project example

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vite, deno

My config (MX Linux 21.3):

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

$ deno --version
deno 1.32.3 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 11.2.214.9
typescript 5.0.3

$ node --version
v18.15.0

$ npm --version
9.5.0
```

Trying to follow the tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDPauM8fZDE
https://github.com/denoland/examples/tree/main/with-vue

```
$ deno run -A npm:create-vite-extra
✔ Project name: … myProject
✔ Select a template: › deno-vue
✔ Select a variant: › TypeScript

Scaffolding project in /myProject...

Done. Now run:

  cd myProject
  deno task dev

$ cd myProject
$ deno task dev
```

I get the error:

```
Task dev deno run -A --node-modules-dir npm:vite
failed to load config from /myProject/vite.config.mts
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on')
    at ensureServiceIsRunning (file:///myProject/node_modules/.deno/esbuild@0.17.16/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2137:15)
    at build (file:///myProject/node_modules/.deno/esbuild@0.17.16/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2011:26)
    at bundleConfigFile (file:///myProject/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.2.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:63875:26)
    at loadConfigFromFile (file:///myProject/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.2.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:63851:31)
    at resolveConfig (file:///myProject/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.2.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:63466:34)
    at createServer (file:///myProject/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.2.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:62752:26)
    at CAC.<anonymous> (file:///myProject/node_modules/.deno/vite@4.2.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:734:30)
```

My 'deno.json' file:

```
{
  "tasks": {
    "dev": "deno run -A --node-modules-dir npm:vite",
    "build": "deno run -A --node-modules-dir npm:vite build",
    "preview": "deno run -A --node-modules-dir npm:vite preview",
    "serve": "deno run --allow-net --allow-read https://deno.land/std@0.157.0/http/file_server.ts dist/"
  }
}
```

My 'vite.config.mts' file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'npm:vite@^4.0.4'
import vue from 'npm:@vitejs/plugin-vue@^4.0.0'

import 'npm:vue@^3.2.45'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
})
```

My 'src/main.ts' file

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

I didn't change anything in those 3 files. They were generated by Deno.

I suppose there is a version issue somewhere, but I've already searched Google (and even tried ChatGPT) for hours, and can't figure out what is causing the issue.